# Passing c# datatable into javascript multi dimentional array list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to pass a datatable from asp.net c# to java script in the following format.

```
var markers = [
{
    "title": 'Campbell Donald',
    "lat": '35.821201',
    "lng": '-78.703884',
    "description": '3100 Blue Ridge Rd,Raleigh,NC,27612'
},
{
    "title": 'Hoffman Byron',
    "lat": '35.723053',
    "lng": '101.7061447',
    "description": '421 N Holly Ave,Siler City,NC,27344'
},
{
    "title": 'Jalan Intan (Gombak)',
    "lat": '3.22317',
    "lng": '101.71588',
    "description": 'Jalan Intan (Gombak), Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
},
{
    "title": 'Jalan Madrasah',
    "lat": '3.218515',
    "lng": '101.717801',
    "description": 'Jalan Madrasah, Kuala Lumpur, Wilayah Persekutuan Kuala Lumpur, 53100'
}
```

];

I tried to assign the marker variable in this way by my code.

```
DataTable dthcp = dbUtil.getHcpbyMapdistance();

    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");
    sb.Append("var markers = [];");
    foreach (object dataRow in dthcp.Rows)
    {
        sb.Append("markers.push('" + string.Format("var jsArray = {0}", serializer.Serialize(dataRow)) + "');");
    }
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TestArrayScript", sb.ToString(),true);
```

My java script part

```
var markers = [];

window.onload = function () {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[1].lat, markers[1].lng),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (i = 1; i <= markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i - 1]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            labelContent: i,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(6, 34),
            labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
            labelInBackground: false
        });

        (function (marker, data) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);

    }
}
```

Please help me to get through this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for JSON rather that javascript array.

You could use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

I will also suggest you to use a [web-method](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) or [generic http handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/353260/ASP-NET-Advanced-Generic-Handler-ASHX) for this type of request.